# Под каким номером в списке идёт первое слово, в котором нет буквы А?

Tags: алгоритм

Все четырёхбуквенные слова, составленные из букв Р, Е, К, А, записаны в алфавитном порядке и пронумерованы, начиная с 1.

Начало списка: 1. АААА, 2. АААЕ, 3. АААК, 4. АААР, 5. ААЕА …

Под каким номером в списке идёт первое слово, в котором нет буквы А?

Comment: О, нас на олимпиаду записали?

Comment: помощь прошу в задании

Comment: Не видно, что помощь просишь. Видно, что спрашиваешь под каким номером слово идет.

Comment: Если не можешь решить, награды недостоин. Эту задачу можно на бумажке карандашом решить, а то и в уме. А за тебя здесь решать не будут.

Comment: @Эникейщик тогда подскажите хоть как решать пожалуйста

Comment: На то и олимпиада, чтобы самостоятельно придумать алгоритм. подсказать тут все равно, что решить.

Comment: https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/test?theme=243

Comment: @KnowLedge вот такой Эникейщик  строгий но справедливый :)

Comment: Подсказываю: Считайте, что буквы - это цифры (и что их только четыре). В каком первом четырехзначном числе нет нуля?

Comment: @Igor скажу глупость число это 1111 ?

Comment: @Leks да, только в четверичной системе счисления

Comment: @Igor  думал что Вы скажете неправильно и я напишу что олимпиады это не мое, а оказывается почему меня до сих пор не выдвинули участвовать в олимпиаде ? :)) P.S. спасибо за подсказку без Вас я бы не решил бы ...

Comment: @Leks Потому что Вы еще не ответили на вопрос задачи :)

Comment: @Igor человек задавший вопрос хотел подсказку :)

Comment: @Leks Хорошо, хорошо, молчу. Постольку-поскольку мы все понимаем, что ответ `85`.

Comment: @Igor не 85))а 86

Comment: @Igor 1111_4 + 1= 86

Comment: @Igor O_o подъехала интрига ...

Comment: @Igor не буду Вас отвлекать всего лишь признаюсь что я не только не знал правильного ответа но не знаю как перевести в четверичную систему счисления. Хорошо, хорошо, молчу. Удачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считайте, что буквы - это цифры (и что их только четыре). В каком первом четырехзначном четверичном числе нет нуля?

> 1111 i.e. EEEE

---

> 86 = 4^3 + 4^2 + 4 + 1 + AAAA

Comment: так 86 и получается

Comment: @KnowLedge Да, забыл ноль посчитать.

Comment: получил число 86  а какой правильный ответ?

Comment: под какой цифрой??????

Comment: @KnowLedge Кхм, кхм. Это и есть правильный ответ: Первое слово, в котором нет буквы А, идет под номером 86.

Comment: задание в форме теста,выбрать одно из пяти нужно,все 5 первых вам предоставлено,не понимаю тогда вообще

Comment: @KnowLedge Это просто первые пять комбинаций из возможных 256-и, для примера. Среди них нет ответа.

Comment: Ничоси, скрывающиеся цитаты